# How do I turn off the monitor when I close the lid?

Tags: dell, screen, lid

My problem is that when lid is closed, it just shows blank screen and not turning off the monitor, so my monitor is always on. But when I use Win 7 and I close the lid it turns off the monitor, so I want my Ubuntu to do the same thing. Can anyone help me?

I have Dell Inspiron 1564

Comment: Why does this one have [solved] in it's headline? What is the solution?

Comment: I fixed my problem by installing the latest graphic card drivers from AMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by installing the latest graphics card drivers from AMD.

Comment: Could you expand the answer a bit and explain where this option appears once you install the graphics card driver?

Answer (score 0):

I currently don't have Ubuntu installed on a laptop, but I believe it should be at:
System settings > Power
you should have an option to choose what to do when the lid is closed.

Comment: In power options (when the lid is closed) I have: Suspend, Hibernate and Do nothing. I pick "Do nothing" because I want my laptop to keep working but I don't want to waste energy when I have lid closed and I want turn off the screen. I hope this is possible.

Comment: Try Brightness and lock, do you have an option there to lock the screen when lid is closed?

Comment: BTW, why not suspend or hibernate the system? I ask because I realize now you want the monitor to actually be off power, which I'm not sure possible without suspend or hibernate. Assuming your swap partition is at least 1.5 the size of your RAM, hibernation should work perfectly.

Comment: I tried Brightness and lock but results are the same and I don't want to suspend or hibernate either because e.g. while I'm downloading something and I'm not using my computer for something different I can close the lid and save energy. When I'm using Win 7 I can close my laptop and screen goes off so I know this can be done but I don't know how to activate this on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I checked the power settings options and there is no option to turn off the monitor when lid is closed. But if you check the "Brightness and lock settings", there is an option to turn off the screen after remaining inactive for a particular period.

Comment: I was trying to do this too but the results are the same; blank screen and monitor still working. I don't know what else I can do.